# How to get relative path of current file to pwd in Vim

Tags: vim

Let's say that my cwd is `/home/rgrinberg/project` and I'm browsing some file `/home/rgrinberg/project/x/y/z.py` and I'd like to get `x/y`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In normal mode:

```
:echo expand('%:h')
```

[Please use vim wiki for further research](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Get_the_name_of_the_current_file)